# Bisection Method for intersection of two functions

Tags: numerical-methods

I know how to use the bisection method when finding roots, however I don't know how to use it for when two lines intersect, any help with this would be much appreciated

Comment: Suppose you have two straight lines as: $f_1(x)=m_1x+c_1\ \ and\ \ f_2(x)=m_2x+c_2$. Now, finding the intersection of these two lines is same as finding the root of the equation $f_1(x)-f_2(x)=0$

Comment: Assuming that the lines are straight and you have the equations for them, you wouldn't need the bisection method. Are the lines straight and do you have the equations for them?

Answer (score 5):

To determine where any two curves $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ intersect (and lines are considered 'curves' for this purpose), simply set $f(x)=g(x)$.  The reason this works, is that you are looking for pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy both equations simultaneously, so to ensure the $y$-coordinates are the same, implies that $f(x)=y=g(x)$.  Now rewrite $f(x)=g(x)$ as $f(x)-g(x)=0$, and your question boils down to finding the root(s) of the function $f-g$.